# Android Studio telling me it cannot resolve symbols?

Tags: android

Android Studio was telling me it couldn't resolve some symbols in my code. After research, it was apparent that my project was API level 23, which wasnt compatible with some of the code. I decided to change it to API level 21.

Below is the previous code in my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.scriptdesigninc.test_app"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
   }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

I was told that I have to change it to the following,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.scriptdesigninc.test_app"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

After I changed it, it told me I am missing the API package and that I have to download it, which I did. Then I clicked "retry" and it said it was unable to sync gradle project.

Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: can you specify which symbols as you said are unresolved..

Comment: Yup, here's a link http://i.imgur.com/bPljsEu.png

Comment: did you try invalidate caches / restart in android studio under file

Comment: I know your problem is solved. But one more suggestion. you are using Https calls which doesnt support Android M. Instead you can use google free provided Volley library. Its very simple and robust. learn more about it here https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
}
```

Add the above dependency in your `build.gradle` file.

This is happening because Android M does not supports the Apache HTTP API

Comment: Very helpful, and fixed most of the issues. But it still left some symbols unresolved.

Comment: Can you specify which symbols?

Comment: Change super.onPostExecute(aVoid) to super.onPostExecute(returnedUser).